# How to parse "adb shell top" to display only CPU or memory usage?

Tags: android, python, adb, cpu

I have the output result from "adb shell top" in a .txt file. I want to get only the CPU usage for my testing app and display it as a table:

```
Time cpu %

1    18   
2    20 
3    15 
4    19
```

I have tried `cat top.txt | grep Cpu | nl > cpu.txt` (followed the instructions from here [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/extract-values-from-top-and-plot-them)), but the file is empty.

Do you have any idea how can I start? I have never used regex and not sure will it help. Please, looking forward hearing any tips :)

```
    User 23%, System 5%, IOW 0%, IRQ 0%
    User 434 + Nice 0 + Sys 106 + Idle 1273 + IOW 10 + IRQ 0 + SIRQ 3 = 1826

     PID PR CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Name
     1868  1  20% S    50 1394620K 175176K  fg u0_a174  com.test.app
    1841  6   2% S    11 1897824K  48632K  fg shell    uiautomator
    4794  1   1% S   148 2334708K 130924K  fg system   system_server
     447  1   1% S    14 422152K  17476K  fg system /system/bin/surfaceflinger
   29195  1   1% S    21 369676K  20040K  fg media
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your `top.txt` sample, I would do the following, step by step:

First, select only the lines for your app `com.test.app` with `grep`:

```
grep com.test.app top.txt
```

Take the third field (delimited by spaces, so this is the CPU usage) by piping into `awk`:

```
grep com.test.app top.txt | awk '{ print $3; }'
```

Add line numbering by piping into `nl` (the `-nln` is for left justification):

```
grep com.test.app top.txt | awk '{ print $3; }' | nl -nln
```

Finally, just prepend your header with `echo` (`-e` and double quotes are needed for newline `\n`):

```
echo -e "Time    cpu %\n" && grep com.test.app top.txt | awk '{ print $3; }' | nl -nln
```

This will give you for the sample `top.txt`:

```
Time    cpu %

1       20%
```

Comment: if you decide to answer an old and pretty low quality question ignoring the `python` tag - at least do your own homework. why spawn multiple processes when `awk` is more than capable of doing everything by itself - printing the header, filtering lines by the pattern, printing line numbers and specific record fields.

Comment: @AlexP. If you'd read the question you'd see OP tried to extract data with unix tools. I've shown how to do that. What is your problem? The question may be mistagged, I actually haven't noticed that, I randomly stumbled upon this question from the Android aspect.